# How to make sure that the PDF attached to the auto email is to the newest information?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is the flow I created through Google Apps Script.

1. Someone writes their information in google form
2. The information is stored into spreadsheet
3. Invoice is created within spreadsheet with the newest information received
4. The invoice is turned into PDF format automatically
5. The newest invoice is attached to the auto sending email
6. The person receives an auto-email with the invoice attached as soon as they submit the google form

The problem is that, when someone submits the google form, they receive an invoice but what they receive is the invoice from the information one before. This then repeats. When someone submits, the information inside the invoice is from the person one before.

I am a starter at Google Script so I have no idea why this is happening.

This is the code I use to send the auto email. I have minimized the code.

```
function for_users2() {

 var title = "【お問い合わせありがとうございます】";

 var name = '名前'; 
 var mail = 'メールアドレス'; 
 var address = "";

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var row = sheet.getLastRow();
 var column = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 var TIMESTAMP_LABEL = 'タイムスタンプ';

 for (var i = 1; i <= column; i++ ) {

 var item = range.getCell(1, i).getValue();


 var value = range.getCell(row, i).getValue();

 if ( item === TIMESTAMP_LABEL ) {
 item = 'お問い合わせ日時';
 }

 if ( item === 'お問い合わせ日時' ) {
 value = Utilities.formatDate(value, 'Asia/Tokyo',"YYYY'年'MM'月'dd'日'HH'時'mm'分'ss'秒'");
 }


 body += "■"+item+"\n";


 body += value + "\n\n";


 if ( item === name ) {
 body = value+" 様\n\n"+body;
 }


 if ( item === mail ) {
 address = value;
 }
 }

 body += body2;

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false&gid=00000000000", {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token}}).getBlob().setName('請求書');



  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    address,
    title,
    body,
    {
      attachments: [pdf],
      name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
    }
 );
  }


There is no error. It's just that the invoice attached is from one previous customer.
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. How do you run the function `for_users2`? 2. If `pdf` of `var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(###)` is the issue, how is the Spreadsheet retrieved by `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` updated?

Comment: 1. There is a trigger and it is set when the google form is sent. And this code is written in spreadsheet script. 2. Sorry I did not quite catch what the question means. However, I can say that there is no issue with the code as I have tested many times. What do you mean by updated?

Comment: I don't know if this information is needed, but once the google from is submitted, the information is written into the spreadsheet and sends specific information to the invoice in another sheet. And that is automatically made into a PDF format. When I check the invoice straight after I submit Google Form, the information is updated on the spreadsheet and invoice but what I was sent is the invoice from the previous information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About Q2, in your question, you say `Invoice is created within spreadsheet with the newest information received`. From this, I thought that you update the Spreadsheet using the submitted values. So I asked about the update. By the way, you also say `I have minimized the code.`. About this, if the Spreadsheet is updated and exported when the form is submitted, how about putting `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before `var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(###)`? But, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. What I meant was that the Spreadsheet is updated and exported when the form is submitted. I will try the `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` and see how it goes. If it still doesn't solve the problem, I will comment. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I inserted `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` but still does the same thing.

Comment: When `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` didn't resolve your issue, as other method, how about putting `Utilities.sleep(5000)` before `var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(###)`? `5000` means 5 seconds waiting. I thought that when the form is submitted, such issue might occur due to the time lag. So for example, it's `5000`, `10000` and so on.

Comment: If `sleep` and the use of both `sleep` and `flush` didn't resolve your issue, I would like to propose to use PropertiesService. For example, as the initial value, it puts the number of rows of the sheet for submitting from the form to the PropertiesService before submitting. When the script is run by the OnFormSubmit trigger, it knows whether the values were put to the Spreadsheet by checking the number of rows.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. `Utilities.sleep(5000)` worked perfectly. Although as it is just a quick measurement, I will keep trying to create a solid base. Once again, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. This method is one of several workarounds. So if you want to accurately check whether the Spreadsheet is updated by the submitted values, please compare the values of rows and/or the values of last row of the sheet with the submitted values. By this, it will close to the complete check. By the way, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Can you post the current solution as an answer and accept it? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to the people who have answered my question. Special thanks to Tanaike who have suggested a workaround where I was able to use as a starter to GAS.

As I used `Utilities.sleep(5000)`, whenever someone submits google form, the invoice produced (PDF format) is updated to the newest info. Since the program I created isn't aimed for very heavy processes, it may be the reason why it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If SpreasheetApp.flush() doesn't seem to be working then you should certainly move to the onFormSubmit - Installable Trigger.

[Triggers - Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

This way you can process the exact values from the form and use the same function you are using now. Instead of fetching the last row values, you can fetch the values from the form submission using this.

```
var name = e.namedValues['Name'][0]; var email = e.namedValues['Email'][0];
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As `Utilities.sleep(5000)` matched perfectly with the current project, I have used it to as a quick measurement. However, I will keep researching to create a better code and your comment will definitely help me. Thank you for your cooperation.